# Argparse shortcut option for combining other options

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say I have an input file option and an output file option.  How can I create an option that combines the two?  For example:

```
$ ./my_script.py -i input.txt -o output.txt
```

could be combined as:

```
$ ./my_script.py --io input_output.txt
```

You might say that I could do `-io` to combine both options, but `-io filename` is a shortcut for `-i -o filename`, not `-i filename -o filename`.

I thought that it might be possible to add `dest=('input', 'output')` to my `.add_argument()` call, but that raised an error that `dest` must be a string.

I tried adding a mutually exclusive group with `--io` on one side and a group of `-i` and `-o` on the other side, but the help texts for `-i` and `-o` did not show up any more when the program was run with `--help`:

```
usage: myscript.py [-h] [--io] [-i INPUT] [-o OUTPUT]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --io        Use file as both input and output
```

Also, the mutually exclusive part didn't seem to work.  I am still allowed to call the script with `--io` and the individual `-i` and `-o` options, and no error is raised.

Here is my skeleton code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="Input file")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output file")

parser.parse_args()
```

The code with groups:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

exclusive = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
exclusive.add_argument("--io", help="Input and Output")

sub = exclusive.add_argument_group()
sub.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="Input file")
sub.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output file")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.io:
    in_file = out_file = args.io
else:
    in_file = args.input
    out_file = args.output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to explain why things don't work than to suggest a solution.

Yes, `dest` must be a string; there's no provision for a list or tuple of `dest` values.  But your `in_file = out_file = args.io` addresses that issue just fine.  You could have also used:

```
 args.in_file=args.out_file = args.io
```

There's nothing wrong with massaging the `args` values after parsing.

`argument_group` is not designed for nesting, nor is it a way of adding 'any' (or 'and') logic to the `mutually_exclusive_group`.  Maybe in the distant future there will be a way of defining a full set of logical combinations, but not now.  Actually it isn't hard to do the tests; it's hard to define the API and the usage formatting.

Also keep in mind that `mutually_exclusive_group` is used to format the usage and test for co_ocurrance of arguments, while `argument_group` is used to group argument help lines.  Two very different purposes.

If `-i` was a `store_true` argument then `-io filename` would be understood as `-i -o filename`.  But translating it too `-i filename -o filename` is not in the current code (and probably not common enough to warrant a patch).

If you still want to use `-i`, `-o` and `--io` (I prefer `--` for 2 character flags) I can suggest a couple of things:

- write a custom usage that demonstrates what you want.  If it is hard to write a clear usage, then your design is probably too complicated.
- do your own `exclusive groups` testing after parsing.  `args.in_file is None` is a good way of testing whether a flag has been used or not.  Another possibility is to define defaults such that you don't care which combination the user uses.

Answer (score 5):

Keep it simple--the exclusive groups code you showed didn't exclude using both forms anyway.  Try this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="Input file")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output file")
parser.add_argument("--io", help="Input and Output")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.io:
    assert args.input is None and args.output is None
    args.input = args.output = args.io
else:
    assert args.input and args.output
```

Comment: It's too bad there isn't something easier.  I decided to use something similar to this, except that I used something a little more user-friendly than an `AssertionError`.