# How do I create an optional argument that is an alias of another argument with a certain value?

Tags: python, argparse

I need to edit a Python 3 program, let's call it `./foo`, that uses `argeparse` to parse its argument list.

Currently, this program allows one to specify an optional input file on the command line. If it is not specified, then foo reads the file `setting.txt`

```
$ ./foo 
$ ./foo --input my_settings.txt
```

The code that does this pretty simple:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--input',
    default='settings.txt'
)
```

The intent was to give personalized settings, but in practice, 99% of people who use the `--input` argument specify one particular file `other_settings.txt`. I'd like to add a mutually exclusive convenience argument, `--common` that is equivalent to the `--input other_settings.txt`

```
# These are the same.
$ ./foo --input other_settings.txt
$ $ ./foo --common
```

What is the recommended way to accomplish this? For example, should I have both arguments write to the same `dest` value? Do I have them write to separate destinations and then add some logic inside the body of the code, similar as was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024501/argparse-shortcut-option-for-combining-other-options)?

Comment: It's simplest to handle interactions between arguments after parsing.  That code is usually simpler and more reliable.  In that case I'd leave the defaults as `None`.  It's easier to check whether your user provided that option that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a mutually exclusive argument group `grp`. I added two arguments to the group in this order:

1. The original argument
2. A new argument with

```
grp.add_argument(
    '--input',
    default='settings.txt'
)
grp.add_argument(
        "--common",
        action="store_const",
        dest="input",
        const="other_settings.txt",
    )
```

This order seems to ensure that the value that is provided when neither of them are specified is `settings.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this by parsing the arguments, and then:

```
 if common is not None:
     input_file = "other_settings.txt"
```